# How to find range

Tags: range, overlap

I have two sets of ranges. Each range is a pair of integers (start and end) representing some sub-range of a single larger range. 
I need to determine which ranges from set A overlap with which ranges from set B.

Comment: Couldn't understand how do you derive that output. Can you please explain a bit? How do you define coverage of coordinate? I observe that second column is also changing. Not sure how.

Comment: If you notice the example you will find 10-12 range is within 10-15 and 10-16. So there are three overlaps. Similarly there are two overlaps for 10-15 (in second row and third row ) and only one overlap for 10-16. Thats how the numbers 3 , 2 and 1 are derived. I have a very large file with many overlaps. I have to count them. I need to use perl for that. I am new to perl, I dont know how to go about it.

Comment: @user2923577 You have presented way, way, waaaaaay too little information on how to calculate these numbers. We cannot read your mind. Also, this is not a question about Perl code, but about how to solve your problem. Generally speaking, you should present Perl code and ask questions about the code.

Comment: As @TLP said, please post your Perl code.  I anticipate there will be some function that computes `$b - $a + 1`.

Comment: Also, have you tried the Beginner's Guide on [PERL.com](http://www.perl.com)?

Answer (score 3):

I think your input got truncated, because I can't see any way to get the last rows of your expected output.

But, for the portion that's there, I think you want a script like this:

```
my %cover;

foreach my $line ( <STDIN> )
{
    chomp $line;
    my ( $tag, $lo, $hi ) = split /\s+/, $line;
    map { $cover{$_}++ } ($lo .. $hi);
}


my $beg = 0;
my $end = 0;
my $cnt = 0;

foreach my $val ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %cover )
{
    if ($cover{$val} != $cnt || $val > $end + 1)
    {
        if ($cnt > 0)
        {
            print "chr1\t$beg\t$end\t$cnt\n";
        }

        $cnt = $cover{$val};
        $beg = $val;
        $end = $val;
    } else
    {
        $end = $val;
    }
}

if ($cnt > 0)
{
    print "chr1\t$beg\t$end\t$cnt\n";
}
```

You didn't tell us, though, what to do with `chr1` or how to related it between the input and output (are there other values that could appear there, for example?) so I just hardcoded that in the output.  You'll have to change that part appropriately.

Also, my script outputs slightly different ranges than your "expected output," specifically where two ranges abut.  My script, for example, outputs

```
chr1    556     579     1
chr1    580     592     2
```

but your expected output gives `580` instead of `579` for the first line.  I'm not sure your expected output is correct.  If you really did want 580 there (which doesn't make a lot of sense), then you could modify the script above to output `$end+1` when `$val == $end+1`.  That just seems weird though.

Here's that modified version of the code that gives the weird behavior when ranges abut:

```
my %cover;

foreach my $line ( <STDIN> )
{
    chomp $line;
    my ( $tag, $lo, $hi ) = split /\s+/, $line;
    map { $cover{$_}++ } ($lo .. $hi);
}


my $beg = 0;
my $end = 0;
my $cnt = 0;

foreach my $val ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %cover )
{
    if ($cover{$val} != $cnt || $val > $end + 1)
    {
        ## unusual value for '$end' when ranges abut.
        $end = $val if ($val == $end + 1);

        if ($cnt > 0)
        {
            print "chr1\t$beg\t$end\t$cnt\n";
        }

        $cnt = $cover{$val};
        $beg = $val;
        $end = $val;
    } else
    {
        $end = $val;
    }
}

if ($cnt > 0)
{
    print "chr1\t$beg\t$end\t$cnt\n";
}
```

Comment: @user2923577 : Be sure to vote up and accept it, if it did solve your problems.  :-)